# Need help figuring out boundaries of a div

Tags: html, css

I've been creating a simple website as part of a project and am struggling figuring out why the contents of a div is expanding outside it. Here is the relevant HTML code:

```css
#links_container {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border: 2px solid white;
  height: 10%;
}
#about_me {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 19.6%;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
#about_me p {
  line-height: 600%;
}
#about_me:hover {
  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
}
#webpage_designs {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 19.6%;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
#webpage_designs p {
  line-height: 600%;
}
#webpage_designs:hover {
  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
}
#resume_link {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 19.6%;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
#resume_link p {
  line-height: 600%;
}
#resume_link:hover {
  background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
}
```

```html
<div id="links_container">

  <div id="about_me">
    <p>About Me</p>
  </div>

  <div id="webpage_designs">
    <p>Webpage Designs</p>
  </div>

  <a href="resume.html">
    <div id="resume_link">
      <p>Resume</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <div id="link_4">
    <p>Link 4</p>
  </div>

  <div id="link_5">
    <p>Link 5</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

All of the divs extend below the border of the div that they're supposed to be contained within and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing some CSS here. I don't quite get why the three first divs have `display: inline-block` but not the last two.

Anyways, if you want to enforce the *contaiment* of the elements within the `#links_container` div, you could use `overflow: hidden` in the parent div. That will hide everything that escapes the bounding box of the layer.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't link the css for the last two divs. They're the same as the first three.